How to minimise execution time in SQL Server in a request containing a loop
I'm new to this group, I have a problem with my SQL Server query, the processing takes too long to execute. I've created indexes, but the processing is still taking too long.
Is there a way to optimise the execution time of this query where I use two loops?
Note: the SI2 table contains around 25 million rows.
DECLARE @SurvenanceLimite INT = 2023;
DECLARE @SURV INT = 2015;

WHILE @SURV <= @SurvenanceLimite
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AnneeSurvenance INT = @SURV;
    DECLARE @AnneeObservation INT = 2023;
    
    WHILE @AnneeSurvenance <= @AnneeObservation
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #LastSit
        SELECT *,
               @SURV AS SURV,
               @AnneeSurvenance AS Annee
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                CD_STE_CPTA,
                --STE_GEST,
                CD_BRCH_CPTA,
                CD_BRCH_GEST,
                GAR_GEST,
                GAR_CPTA,
                CD_DESC_SIN,
                CD_CAT_NAT,
                EXER_INV,
                EXER_SIN,
                NUM_SIN,
                DAT_SIT,
                MT_VAL_CUM,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXER_SIN, NUM_SIN, GAR_CPTA, GAR_GEST ORDER BY DAT_SIT DESC, NUM_MVT DESC) AS RN,
                NUM_MVT
            FROM SI2
            WHERE DAT_SIT <= DATEFROMPARTS(@AnneeSurvenance, 08, 31) AND EXER_SIN = @SURV
        ) AS C 
        WHERE RN = 1;

        SET @AnneeSurvenance = @AnneeSurvenance + 1;
    END;
  
    SET @SURV = @SURV + 1;
END;

The main problem is the execution time is too long for this request how to optimize knowing that I have created indexes but always the same thing?

Short answer: eliminate the loops. Database servers are set-based systems. Any time you use a loop you're forcing it to go RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row). There's no reason to use a while loop here when you could use cross applys to supply the range of values needed. Microsoft makes it extremely easy now with the GENERATE_SERIES function.

but I don't see another method except going through a loop, if you see another method please add an example at the bottom!

You don't need loops here (or anywhere, ever). You can just use a couple of GENERATE_SERIES calls to create multiple rows from nothing, then APPLY the rest of the query. If you are on an older version then you can use one of Itzik Ben-Gan's functions.
INSERT INTO #LastSit
SELECT C.*,
       g1.value AS SURV,
       g2.value AS Annee
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(2015, 2023) g1
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(g1.value, 2023) g2
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT 
                CD_STE_CPTA,
                --STE_GEST,
                CD_BRCH_CPTA,
                CD_BRCH_GEST,
                GAR_GEST,
                GAR_CPTA,
                CD_DESC_SIN,
                CD_CAT_NAT,
                EXER_INV,
                EXER_SIN,
                NUM_SIN,
                DAT_SIT,
                MT_VAL_CUM,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXER_SIN, NUM_SIN, GAR_CPTA, GAR_GEST ORDER BY DAT_SIT DESC, NUM_MVT DESC) AS RN,
                NUM_MVT
            FROM SI2
            WHERE DAT_SIT <= DATEFROMPARTS(g2.value, 08, 31) AND EXER_SIN = g1.value
) AS C 
WHERE C.RN = 1;

Having said that, there is probably still further room for improvement. It's unclear exactly what you are doing with all these rows, but it could probably be improved wth running SUM window functions instead of cross-joining everything.

when executing your request, I got this error, I didn't understand the problem  : Msg 208, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 10
Invalid object name 'GENERATE_SERIES'.

I think the function is not recognised in my sql server, how can I proceed?

Which version do you have? On SQL2019 or older you need some other function, see the link I mentioned. On SQL2022 you need to be on compatibility level 160.

I have the 2019 version, I think I don't have this functionality, can you please suggest another method than this or another tip to minimize execution time!?

ahh I've just seen the link, but I think the article is a bit vast, there are many demonstrations but I have not found exactly what I'm looking for to replace the GENERATE function unless I'm mistaken, perhaps because my level of sql server is interesting, can you help me please?

Best solution there without resorting to weird features or a permanent table is GetNumsAlanCharlieItzikBatch

This tip may be interesting, but how do I apply it? Can you show me how in a new answer and method 2 please, I need this urgently to minimise the time?

Just run the script to create the function, then use that function https://dbfiddle.uk/O1Sd5sM_ I'm not here to "urgently" make answers for you, sorry. You can employ a consultant if it's urgent.

Thank you for your clarification. I asked you if you could help me urgently and not something else,
I'll try to do what you told me first.

I've just tried this procedure, but I have the impression that it takes longer than the basic loop, do you have an explanation please?
